# Obtaining a value from a custom setting

Tags: apex, customsetting

I have a protected custom setting that I am querying. I have the following statement:

App_*name*_c key = App_*name*_c.getValues('secret');

When I run this in the console it works. However, when I run this in the class, it returns this:

System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your List code? The problem is there, it's telling you the query is not returning any values and we cannot tell without the code.

Comment: Did you try defining the class without sharing to see if that gave a different result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you per any chance getting `System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject`  when you run it **in test code ?**

Custom settings, are data and are just like most sObject data not available by default in test code. For good practise, testing your logic is done data independant and test data is generated in the test itself. You can create and insert custom settings like any sObject with DML.

```
insert new CustomSetting__c(Name='dummyt', fieldOne__c= 'value1', field2__c='value2');
```